# How to use ListIterator effectively?

Tags: java, regex, string, iterator

I have a method like the following -:

```
public void apply(ArrayList<String> tokenStream);
```

in which I accept a list of string tokens like the following - tokenStream = ("I am good" , "I am bad") , and I want to be able to convert these tokens in the tokenStream list into individual tokens and add them back to the same list in the manner that after the method execution is over I should have - tokenStream = ("I" , "am" ,"good" , "I" , "am" , "bad"), How can I use ListIterator to solve this problem? Basically I want to be able to split the individual strings in the tokenStream and add them back to the same stream object using ListIterators set and remove methods, how do I do it?

This is specifically what I am trying to do

```
public void apply(tokenstream stream){

        if (stream != null) {

            ArrayList<String> splittedTokens = new ArrayList<>();

            while (stream.hasNext()) {

                String token = stream.next();

                String[] splitTokens = token.split("\\s+");

                for (int i = 0; i < splitTokens.length; ++i)
                    splittedTokens.add(splitTokens[i]);
            }

            // set the stream to hold this new formed stream with tokens
            stream.set((String[]) splittedTokens.toArray());
        }
    }
```

I am trying to remove the whitespace from the tokens in the token stream object which internally uses an array list to store the tokens and this tokenstream class has a set of methods complementing those of the ListIterator class like set and remove, so how do I go about implementing that?

Comment: Why do you care about using `ListIterator`? What have you tried so far? Post some code.

Comment: okk lemme post the exact thing for you

Comment: @PhilippReichart : kindly look at the explanation now.

Comment: How does your current code not work? Is `tokenstream` a `ListIterator`? If so, I doubt you can achieve what you're trying with `ListIterator.set()`, it only "replaces the last element returned by next or previous", so there seems to be no way to add more items to the iterator than it originally had. If `tokenstream` is an `ArrayList`, use Evgeniy's answer below.

Comment: The tokenstream class has a set method that uses a set method internally on the array list being used by the token stream object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task the best way seems to be to create a temp list, iterate tokenStream splitting tokens and adding them to the temp list, then clear tokenStream and addAll from temp

Comment: so this should mean something like this then, create a tempTokenList of splitted tokens and then adding it to the original list in the following way : tokenStream.set(tempTokenList) , is it what you are saying ?

Comment: @AnkitSablok Right.  Call `tokenStream.clear();` followed by `tokenStream.addAll(tempTokenList);`

Comment: ArrayList<String> tokenStream: tokenStream.clear() - remove all elements;  tokenStream.addAll(splittedTokens);